# A shorter way to extract last set of digits starting from the back

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to extract the last set of digits from a string without doing this.

```
"sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad"

str_remove("sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad","[:alpha:]+$")
[1] "sdkjfn45sdjk54()"

str_remove(str_remove("sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad","[:alpha:]+$"), "\\(")
[1] "sdkjfn45sdjk54)"

str_remove(str_remove(str_remove("sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad","[:alpha:]+$"), "\\("), "\\)")
[1] "sdkjfn45sdjk54"

str_extract(str_remove(str_remove(str_remove("sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad","[:alpha:]+$"), "\\("), "\\)"), "\\d+$")
[1] "54"
```

because the patterns are uncertain. I am aware that stringi has a str_extract_from_last function but I need to stick to base R or stringR.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `sub("^.*?(\\d+).*$", "\\1", "sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead regex.

```
string <- "sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad"
stringr::str_extract(string, '(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)')
#[1] "54"
```

Using the same regex in base R :

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr('(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)', string, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
```

This extracts the set of numbers which is not followed by any number so last set of numbers.

Comment: Thanks Ronak! Could you walk me through the regex for this -  '(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)'?

Comment: `(\\d+)` is one or more digits. `(?!.*\\d)` is a bit more: `(?!` is negative look-ahead, meaning it is checked and matched, but not "captured" with the pattern. (I'd think a `$` might be needed, as in `(?!.*\\d)$`, but perhaps not.) A good reference for regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272, recognize though that that is generic regex, and R requires double-backslashes whereever that guide uses a single-backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_extract_all` and grab just the last one in each vector.

```r
library(stringr)
quux <- str_extract_all(c("a", "sdkjfn45sdjk54()ad"), "[0-9]+")
sapply(quux, `[`, lengths(quux))
# [1] NA   "54"
```

I use `sapply` because I'm guessing that you have more than one string. `str_extract_all` will return a `list`, where each element is zero or more strings extracted from the source. Since we're only interested in one of those, we can use `sapply`.

One might be tempted to use `sapply(., tail, 1)`, but if zero are found, then it will be `character(0)`, not empty or `NA`. I'm inferring that `NA` would be a good return when the pattern is not found.